# How to resize tableview cell height based upon its visible elements?

Tags: swift, uitableview

In the code below is a function that hides UITableView Cell elements when a button is tapped. How would I resize the cell height based upon the remaining visible elements? Each cell is a row.

I tried using automatic UITableView.automaticDimension to resize the cell but that didn't work.

Here's my vision for how this custom cell should work: the cell is displayed with its full contents once created. When a certain button is tapped, all the elements of the cell below the button are hidden leaving only the button and the elements at the same height level as the button remaining with the cell height readjusted to the visible elements. Then, once that that button is tapped again, the full contents of the cell are shown once more with the appropriate cell size to accommodate it.

```
func customCellDidTapCollapse(_ cell: customCell) {
    if collapsed {
        cell.item1.isHidden = false
        cell.item2.isHidden = false
        cell.item3.isHidden = false
        cell.item4.isHidden = false
        collapsed = false
    } else {
        cell.item1.isHidden = true
        cell.item2.isHidden = true
        cell.item3.isHidden = true
        cell.item4.isHidden = true
        collapsed = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of hiding elements set their height to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use tableView(_:heightForRowAt:) method and return 0 or other non-zero value based on your 'collapsed' boolean.

Check more here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

1. declare a boolean var in DataModel like "isOpen" or "opened"
2. Initialize all data's "opened" var as false
3. In your tableViewDelegation, override a func

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   if data[indexPath.row].opened {
       return 150
   } else {
       return 50
   }
   ```

   }
4. Override tableViewDelegate (_:didSelectRowAt:)

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   //If last opened cell is different than selected now, close the last opened cell

   if lastOpened != indexPath.row {
      data[lastOpened].opened = false
   }
   //Hold the last opened cell index
   lastOpened = indexPath.row
   let isOpen = data[indexPath.row].opened
   //Open/close
   data[indexPath.row].opened = isOpen ? false : true
   myTable.reloadData()
   ```

   }